# SparkSQL joining parent/child datasets

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using SparkSQL 2.2.0 to load data from Cassandra and index it Elasticsearch. The data I have consists of customers (first table `people`) and orders (second table `orders`).
Table orders has a column `person_id` that points to the the corresponding customer.
My need is to query (and index later in Elasticsearch) the `people` table and the `orders` so I can have for each customer the number of orders she purchased.
The easiest approach I figured out is to read the two tables into `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset<Row>`s and make a **join** on the `person_id` column. Then I `groupBy(person_id)`.
That gives me a Dataset with two columns: `person_id` and `count` which I am obliged to join back with the `people` table so I can have the count with the other person data.

```
Dataset<Row> peopleWithOrders = people.join(orders, people.col("id").equalTo(orders.col("person_id")), "left_outer");

Dataset<Row> peopleOrdersCounts = peopleWithOrders.groupBy("id").count().withColumnRenamed("id", "personId");

Dataset<Row> peopleWithOrderCounts = people.join(personsOrdersCounts, people.col("id").equalTo(peopleOrdersCounts.col("personId")), "left_outer")
            .withColumnRenamed("count", "nbrOfOrders")
            .select("id", "name", "birthDate", "nbrOfOrders");
```

The `people` table has 1_000_000 rows and the `orders` one 2_500_000. Each customer has 2 or 3 orders.
I am using a MAC Book pro, with a 2,2 GHz Intel Core i7 Processor and 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 Memory. All of Cassandra, Spark 2.2 master and (single) worker are on the same machine.
These 3 joins take 15 to 20 seconds.
My question is: is there some room for performance gains. Do *Window Aggregate Functions* have benefits since I see ShuffleMapTask in the logs.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the first step is unnecessary. You could just do this:

```
Dataset<Row> peopleOrdersCounts = orders.groupBy("person_id").count();

Dataset<Row> peopleWithOrderCounts = people.join(personsOrdersCounts, people.col("id").equalTo(peopleOrdersCounts.col("personId")), "left_outer")
            .withColumnRenamed("count", "nbrOfOrders")
            .select("id", "name", "birthDate", "nbrOfOrders");
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that's true. My bad. But that's still "relatively slow" (ab 16s). I was wondering if the "Window Aggregate Functions" would help or is this the normal way to do it

Comment: As far as I know, this is the way to do it. Especially, in case of a 'group by'.You can look into User-Defined Aggregate Functions (UDAF) but even those are for specific cases. Are there any other operations that may be slowing this down?